# assign values to array and then refernce them

Tags: php, arrays

Not sure why I am having such a problem with this

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$pagename = array(home => My Home, about => About Us, contact => Contact Us);

echo "You are on the" . $pagename[$page] . "page";
```

the URL would be

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/subpage.php?page=contact
```

The echo should say "You are on the Contact Us page.

Comment: And what does it say instead? Looking at your code i'd guess `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your array definition is using constants instead fo strings as keys. add quotes to keys.

```
array('home' => 'My Home', 'about' => 'About Us', 'contact' => 'Contact Us');
```

Comment: on top of that, your array elements are equal to unquoted strings as well.

Comment: basically, you have to quote strings, and associative keys are strings.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because you lack "" in your string?

```
$pagename = array("home" => "My Home", "about" => "About Us", "contact" => "Contact Us");
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your problem. Looking only at your code, it looks like you forgot to quote your strings in the array.

```
$pagename = array(home => My Home, about => About Us, contact => Contact Us);
```

Would become

```
$pagename = array('home' => 'My Home', 'about' => 'About Us', 'contact' => 'Contact Us');
```